# How do I get the RSSI values of the connected android phone using Arduino?

Tags: bluetooth, rssi

I need to get the RSSI values of the android phone using Arduino. Only the RSSI of the connected android phone.

I haven't tried any method yet. I need suggestions on what components should I buy. Or is it possible to make it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by measuring the RSSI?